# How to replace letters in a string with specific integer values?

Tags: c, string, replace, char, int

I have a wriiten a C program that contains a char array 'long_string' that looks something like this.

```
 long_string[16] = "AHDAHDAHDAHDAHDA";
```

I wish to replace the letters in the string as follows: 
A-0, H-1, D-2.

Could somebody tell me how could I achieve this? I tried to look online but most of the cases show the conversion of letters to there ASCII values which is not what I need. THank you for your time in advance :)

Comment: To be clear, you want this string to convert to `"0120120120120120120"`?

Comment: SO is no code-writing service. Please show what you have done on your own. There are many websites for a simple substitution algorithm.

Comment: You should try something, and if you're definitely stuck come again and post the code you have tried, what you expected it to do, what it did instead / what compiler errors you got / where it crashed at runtime. If you really have no clue how to have a go at it, then you should find yourself an actual learning resource for C.

Comment: @Goldengirl it is important to know the difference between the character `'1'` and the integer `1` in C. I mention this because you refer to the 0, 1, 2 as "integer" in the title, while your question makes it sound like you want the *characters* instead.

Comment: @Olaf: I am sorry to have offended you but I think you may have missed the point where I mention that I am just a beginner and still experimenting with C. I post this question to ask for help(from the people willing to help) thats all. I dont mean to offend anybody :)

Comment: Yeah.  Is 'A' to become '0' or '\0'?

Comment: I did not miss that point. But you should be aware that SO is no tutorial site. For the question asked, there are many solutions to be found by a simple search with your prefered search engine. So it is not a matter of C programming skills, but possibly finding the right search terms. And that is no SO issue either. And, no, it takes much more to offend me.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Sorry I missed the quotes in your comment. I am trying to replace the characters with integers( as mentioned in my question).. i.e 012 for "AHD" and not "012"

Comment: Just a hint: do not think of "replace", but "build a new string as commanded by the one given"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have defined your string, it won't be null terminated (16 is not enough to fit in also the null terminator). Other than that, what you want should be fairly easy:

```
int i = 0;
char long_string[] = "AHDAHDAHDAHDAHDA";
int len = strlen(long_string);
for(i = 0; i<len; i++)
{
  if(long_string[i] == 'A')
   long_string[i] = '0';
  else if(long_string[i] == 'H')
   long_string[i] = '1';
  // etc.
}
```

Comment: If/else if "ugly". A switch would work better in this case.

Comment: @MiguelCunha: it is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = 0;
for( ; i < size ; i++ ){

  switch( long_string[i] ){
    case 'A':
      long_string[i] = '0';
      break;
    // and so on...
  }

}
```

Comment: This is a hard-coded way of doing. This won't solve the problem if there are other letters

Comment: What? A value is 0. H value is 1. D value is 2. M value is whatever he wants... He needs to define values for letters...

Comment: What i guess the OP wants is a generic way to assign these values. These values will be decided when the string in taken as input, and according to that string.

Comment: No. The title is "How to replace letters in a string with specific integer values?", so specific values means that he needs to tell the program what specific values are...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to translate uppercase alpha chars, you can use a lookup table and index it with the char value less 'A', eg:

```
                  //ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
const char xlat[]=("0  2   1                  ");
..
..

newChar=xlat[oldChar-'A'];
```

or, for what you seem to want, the more general form:

```
const char xlat[]=("\x00\x20\x20\x02\x20\x20\x20\x01\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20");
```

Note that translating the chars into a set that includes '\0' will render the output array unuseable as a C-style string.